# Private/public static member function

Tags: c++, static, member

I was reading before that static member functions of a class is similar to a global function. But this should depend on whether or not the static member function is public/private right?

For example:

```
class A
{
  private:
  static void aFunc();
};

int main()
{
  A::aFunc();
}
```

In this case I **wouldn't** be able to call the static member function inside `main()` correct? If I instead had made it public, I can call it, just like a global function?

Comment: There should be a space between the void and aFunc(), I don't know why it's displaying without the space.

Comment: It's C++, right? You should tag the question with the language (e.g. 'c++').

Comment: yes sorry I will edit

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does depend on the access modifier.  If the function is public, then it is somewhat similar to a global function, but unlike a global function it has access to class members and has to be called with the class scope (prefixed with `A::` in your example), to mention just a couple of differences.

BTW, when you call it in main(), you should just have

```
A::aFunc()
```

No need to stick `void` in there.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a static member function is similar to a non-member function in that you do not need to call it for an object of associated class type, but it obeys the usual class member access rules like a non-static member function.

In this case, you are correct to suggest that `A::aFunc` is inaccessible from `main`. However, your calling syntax is incorrect. You do not need to include the return type:

```
A::aFunc();
```